# Editing APEX plugin custom attributes

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I pulled a plug-in from the Customer Tracker sample apex app called "HTML 5 Bar Chart" and I wanted to edit one of the plug-in's custom attributes.  This plugin accesses files from the cloud.  I was wondering if anyone could walk me through how to find these files and store them locally so that I could edit a few features of the plug-in.  Feel free to comment if you need any additional info on the plug-in to answer the question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you can see all the resources that a web page accesses (any, not just APEX) in your browser dev tools (resources tab) - I'm using chrome and edge.

Comment: I found the files and uploaded them and removed the file urls to load but now I'm getting an error that the files are not declared in the source code.  Since the file names stayed the same I can assume it's because the syntax used for referencing the file only works for the cloud ones, is there a way to change this syntax easily?  Or is there a way for me to upload my own files to the cloud?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't be of help on this one. Debugging and testing this for you is going to be a long and tedious process and I don't have the resources to do that.